# $\lim_{t \to \infty}t^p P[|X|>t]=0$ then $X \in L_{q}$

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces

I have problems concluding this exercise.

If
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}t^p P[|X|>t]=0$$
for $p>0$,  then $X \in L_{q}$ for all $q \in (0,p)$

I know that

$$E|X^q|=\int_{0}^{\infty}qt^{q-1}P(X>t)dt.$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}qt^{q-1}P(X>t)dt \leq \int_{0}^{\infty}pt^{p-1}P(X>t)dt.$$
Since $q \in (0,p)$, but I do not know if I could apply the limit in both sides and take it into the integral. Any help? Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hypothesis
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}t^p P[|X|>t]=0$$
can be relaxed to
$$M:=\sup_{ 1 \le t < \infty} t^p P[|X|>t]<\infty \,.$$.
Under this second hypothesis, using the formula
$$E[|X|^q]=\int_{0}^{\infty} qt^{q-1}P(|X|>t) \, dt \,,$$
we get for $q<p$ that
$$E[|X|^q] \le \int_{0}^{1} qt^{q-1}  \, dt + \int_{1}^{\infty} qt^{q-1}Mt^{-p} \, dt =1+\frac{Mq}{p-q} <\infty \,.$$

Comment: So, in the first expression after the inequality, you bound with the probability and the second expression is a finite integral since $q<p$, right?

Comment: @Bayesianguy Exactly, since $q<p$ the power of $t$ in the second integrand is less than $-1$.

Comment: Oooooh, thanks. All clear and concise. Hope to see your helpful advices in future post.